# Can you pass a function as an attribute inline in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to do this, but inline:

```
<Backdrop closeClick={this.zoomOut.bind(this)} />


zoomOut () {
  this.setState({ zoom: false })
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but do you mean like `<Backdrop closeClick={() => this.setState({ zoom: false })} />`?

Comment: As a best practice, bind all action in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inline arrow function:

```
<Backdrop closeClick={() => this.setState({ zoom: false })} />
```